# How to pass AJAX response to React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, components

I'm sending AJAX request:

```
ajax{
  request
  response
}
```

after receiving a response I would like to pass this data into:

```
React.render(Component data={fromAjax}, div).
```

I'm making ajax call outside of the component and I'm not sure what is the best way to pass the data down to the component.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: can i ask you why you are not using fetch ?

Comment: Due to the complexity of the app I must use it like this without fetching the data in ComponentDidMount and then updating the state.

Comment: use React State to pass data. When you get response in ajax then do `this.setState({response  :response})` and pass data in the component `data={response}`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use props so when you pass your data with props you get access to all your props value by deconstructing them Exemple:

```
const yourComponent = ({...props}) => console.log(props);
```